# Selenium web scraping of Indeed: Script returns raise TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on creating a script to web scrape job postings on Indeed that will capture title, company, location and job description. Currently my script will iterate through the first five pages and print out a dataframe of each. However, my dataframe for Page 2 will only include 3 of the 15 job postings. I think this might be due to the pop up box that shows up asking for your email. In order to address this, I tried incorporating a .click to exit out of the popout. Unfortunately, this caused a return of "Timeout Exception". I added in element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "popover-x-button-close icl-CloseButton"))) hoping that it would fix the issue, but no dice so far. Additionally, when I export to CSV, the only page of results that gets put into the CSV is page 5.  I've included my code below. My apologies if these are very straightforward problems, I only started learning Python in order to do job code research three days ago. Thank you in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,1400")

PATH = "C://Program Files (x86)//chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

for i in range(0,50,10):
    driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=chemical%20engineer&l=united%20states&start='+str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    jobtitles = []
    companies = []
    locations = []
    descriptions = []



    jobs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("slider_container")

    for job in jobs:

            jobtitle = job.find_element_by_class_name('jobTitle').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            jobtitles.append(jobtitle)
            company = job.find_element_by_class_name('companyName').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            companies.append(company)
            location = job.find_element_by_class_name('companyLocation').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            locations.append(location)
            description = job.find_element_by_class_name('job-snippet').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            descriptions.append(description)
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "popover-x-button-close icl-CloseButton")))
            close_popup = driver.find_element_by_class_name("popover-x-button-close icl-CloseButton")
            close_popup.click()



    df_da=pd.DataFrame()
    df_da['JobTitle']=jobtitles
    df_da['Company']=companies
    df_da['Location']=locations
    df_da['Description']=descriptions
    print(df_da)
    df_da.to_csv('C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/AZNext/file_name1.csv')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here:

1. The pop-up appears only once, only on the second page while you are waiting for this element each loop iteration. You should check if this element appears and only if it appeared to click it. Otherwise just pass.
2. This element has several class name attributes. So you should use CSS Selector or XPath to locate it, not `by_class_name` since this method is accepting a single class name, not a sequence of class names separated by spaces.
3. You can use `click()` method directly on the returned by `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.popover-x-button-close.icl-CloseButton")))` element, no need to get this element again with `driver.find_element`

I suggest something like the folllowing:

```py
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument("window-size=1400,1400")

PATH = "C://Program Files (x86)//chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

for i in range(0,50,10):
    driver.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=chemical%20engineer&l=united%20states&start='+str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    jobtitles = []
    companies = []
    locations = []
    descriptions = []



    jobs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("slider_container")

    for job in jobs:

            jobtitle = job.find_element_by_class_name('jobTitle').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            jobtitles.append(jobtitle)
            company = job.find_element_by_class_name('companyName').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            companies.append(company)
            location = job.find_element_by_class_name('companyLocation').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            locations.append(location)
            description = job.find_element_by_class_name('job-snippet').text.replace("new", "").strip()
            descriptions.append(description)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.popover-x-button-close.icl-CloseButton"))).click()
            except:
                pass



    df_da=pd.DataFrame()
    df_da['JobTitle']=jobtitles
    df_da['Company']=companies
    df_da['Location']=locations
    df_da['Description']=descriptions
    print(df_da)
    df_da.to_csv('C:/Users/Dan/Desktop/AZNext/file_name1.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! This fixed the pop-up issue for me, but now I run into the issue that after closing the pop-up and cycling through the pages, the script only returns one page into the data frame. It also on occasion only returns part of the data from a page. EX page 2 will return info for the first 3 jobs as part of my print(df_da), but nothing for the next 12.  Additionally, it seems to take a very long time to run the script (averaging around 6 minutes and 45 seconds for the 5 pages, around 1 minute to 1.5 minutes per page) Do you have any suggestions? Thank you again!  @Prophet

Comment: @Wasian Here is StackOverflow each question should be about one specific problem. So we resolved the problem you came here with. I can, maybe, help you with the next problems as well, but you should open a new, separate question about each specific problem.

Comment: So, since this problem is resolved please accept my answer to mark the problem resolved. And, again, you can ask a new question for the current problem.

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know about the process of submitting questions. I'll make a separate question for my new script problem. Thank you again!